# How to "reset" next indexPath.row to become current indexPath.row?

Tags: ios, didselectrowatindexpath, nsindexpath

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

self.selectedTrack = self.SPTrackList[indexPath.row];
self.selectedTrackRow = indexPath.row;

self.nextTrack = self.SPTrackList[indexPath.row +1];

[self playTrack:self.selectedTrack];

}
```

Hi -- How can I "reset" self.nextTrack to become self.selectedTrack?  I've tried self.nextTrack = self.selectedTrack, but that will only work once.  I'm guessing I need to traverse -- if that's the right word -- and move the indexPath of self.selectedTrack and self.nextTrack forward?

```
- (IBAction)nextPressd:(id)sender {
[self playTrack:self.nextTrack];

//self.nextTrack now be new self.selectedTrack via indexPath.row??

  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `self.nextTrack  = self.selectedTrack;` ?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear enough.  i've tried that.  Not what I'm looking for.  If I did that, IBAction nextPressed will  play track B, but then will revert back to track A.

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you explain what is your intended functionality and what is happening now ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just trying to play the next track in my array.  Right now, it will initial play self.selectedTrack when cell on tableview is tapped.  When next is pressed, it plays the next track....but that's it.  It doesn't go anywhere else. :/  Sorry.  I'm new and still learning to articulate my problems

Comment: So you need to play next track when a track is finished playing right ? Or you need to play next track when user again tapped next ?

Comment: when next is tapped. i guess, basically, increment the self.selectedTrack[indexPath.row] by +1 everytime the user tap next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to play the next track from your array, you need to keep track the current playing track and that index. You can do it like:

```
- (IBAction)nextPressd:(id)sender
{
   self.selectedTrackRow += 1;
   self.nextTrack = self.SPTrackList[self.selectedTrackRow];
   [self playTrack:self.nextTrack];
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOD! THANK YOU so much!! I spent 4 hours on this.  :(